# Given a number n, list all n-digit numbers such that each number does not have repeating digits

Tags: java, c, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to solve the following problem. Given an integer, n, list all n-digits numbers such that each number does not have repeating digits.

For example, if n is 4, then the output is as follows:

```
0123
0124
0125
...
9875
9876
Total number of 4-digit numbers is 5040
```

My present approach is by brute-force. I can generate all n-digit numbers, then, using a Set, list all numbers with no repeating digits. However, I'm pretty sure there is a faster, better and more elegant way of doing this.

I'm programming in Java, but I can read source code in C.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell what exactly brute force method you are trying? It would be better if you include your generating combination routine (function or method )

Comment: It looks like a simple exercise. The guys here are too kind to give you their solutions. I would recommend you to give out your attempt (code) and ask about where you stuck, what is wrong, or why is it not efficient enough, etc...

Comment: @Nin totally agree with you. But before explaining the problem here the guys have already given her straightforward answer. A simple google search and geeksforgeeks would do the same

Comment: @Maribell, can we avoid leading zero?

Comment: You may want to clarify whether you  want all numbers up to n digits or just n digits.  You used 0123 in your example, which is n-1 digits in your n=4 example.  This changes the acceptable answer to a sequence like 9*9*8*7...

Comment: Also the meaning of repeated digits used in the question isn't fully clear to me - without looking at the answer. Clearly 3122 has 2 as a repeated digit, but for 3212 it is less clear if 2 is repeated or not - and I would prefer the formulation: "without using any digit more than once".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, you have **10** options for the first number, **9** for the second, **8** for the 3rd, and **7** for the 4th.  So, **10 * 9 * 8 * 7 = 5040**.

Programmatically, you can generate these with some combinations logic.  Using a functional approach usually keeps code cleaner; meaning build up a new string recursively as opposed to trying to use a StringBuilder or array to keep modifying your existing string.

**Example Code**

The following code will generate the permutations, without reusing digits, without any extra set or map/etc.

```
public class LockerNumberNoRepeats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Total combinations = " + permutations(4));
    }

    public static int permutations(int targetLength) {
        return permutations("", "0123456789", targetLength);
    }

    private static int permutations(String c, String r, int targetLength) {
        if (c.length() == targetLength) {
            System.out.println(c);
            return 1;
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length(); ++i) {
            sum += permutations(c + r.charAt(i), r.substring(0,i) + r.substring(i + 1), targetLength);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
...
9875
9876
Total combinations = 5040
```

**Explanation**

Pulling this from a comment by @Rick as it was very well said and helps to clarify the solution.

> So to explain what is happening here - it's recursing a function which takes three parameters: a list of digits we've already used (the string we're building - c), a list of digits we haven't used yet (the string r) and the target depth or length. Then when a digit is used, it is added to c and removed from r for subsequent recursive calls, so you don't need to check if it is already used, because you only pass in those which haven't already been used.

Comment: So to explain what is happening here - it's recursing a function which takes three parameters: a list of digits we've already used (the string we're building - c), a list of digits we haven't used yet (the string r) and the target depth or length.

Then when a digit is used, it is added to c and removed from r for subsequent recursive calls, so you don't need to check if it is already used, because you only pass in those which haven't already been used.  Nice finesse.

Comment: @John Many thanks, this works as a charm and is much faster than my brute-force approach.

Comment: @Rick - Awesome explanation.  I meant to go back and add one in the morning.  I'll include it in the solution with your name.

Comment: @MaribellPinaGriego - No problem at all.  FYI, there is probably an iterative approach to this using a stack + while loop that would be even faster with basically the same logic.  Recursive solutions are usually the simplest to understand and the least code but they are rarely the fastest as all the nested function calls are not optimal.

Comment: Technically he has 9 options for the first number since a 0 would make it a n-1 digit number.  But the question makes that confusing.

Comment: Yeah numerically speaking you're right.  But his example explicitly had leading 0's and his math adds up to using 0 first :).  In practice, it may be more like 9*9*8*7=4536 I guess to avoid leading-0 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

it's easy to find a formula. i.e.

if `n=1` there are `10` variants.

if `n=2` there are `9*10` variants.

if `n=3` there are `8*9*10` variants.

if `n=4` there are `7*8*9*10` variants.

Answer (score 0):

Note the symmetry here:

```
0123
0124
...
9875
9876
```

9876 = 9999 - 123

9875 = 9999 - 124

So for starters you can chop the work in half.

It's possible that you might be able to find a regex which covers scenarios such that if a digit occurs twice in the same string then it matches/fails.

Whether the regex will be faster or not, who knows?

Specifically for four digits you could have nested For loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
       if (j != i) {
           for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
               if ((k != j) && (k != i)) {
                   for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++) {
                       if ((m != k) && (m != j) && (m != i)) {
                           someStringCollection.add((((("" + i) + j) + k) + m));
```

(etc)

Alternatively, for a more generalised solution, this is a good example of the handy-dandy nature of recursion.  E.g. you have a function which takes the list of previous digits, and required depth, and if the number of required digits is less than the depth just have a loop of ten iterations (through each value for the digit you're adding), if the digit doesn't exist in the list already then add it to the list and recurse.  If you're at the correct depth just concatenate all the digits in the list and add it to the collection of valid strings you have.

Answer (score 0):

Backtracking method is also a brute-force method.

```
private static int pickAndSet(byte[] used, int last) {
    if (last >= 0) used[last] = 0;
    int start = (last < 0) ? 0 : last + 1;
    for (int i = start; i < used.length; i++) {
        if (used[i] == 0) {
            used[i] = 1;
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static int get_series(int n) {
    if (n < 1 || n > 10) return 0;
    byte[] used = new byte[10];
    int[] result = new int[n];

    char[] output = new char[n];

    int idx = 0;
    boolean dirForward = true;
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        result[idx] = pickAndSet(used, dirForward ? -1 : result[idx]);
    if (result[idx] < 0) {  //fail, should rewind.
      if (idx == 0) break;      //the zero index rewind failed， think all over.

      dirForward = false;
      idx --;
      continue;
    } else {//forward.
        dirForward = true;
    }

    idx ++;
    if (n == idx) {
        for (int k = 0; k < result.length; k++) output[k] = (char)('0' + result[k]);
        System.out.println(output);
        count ++;
        dirForward = false;
        idx --;
    }
    }
    return count;
}
```